# IE8: Rearranging nodes with Javascript appears to be dropping event handlers

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-8

I have a table with a little button on the side which automatically moves to whatever row the user's mouse is over. When the mouse moves, the button's containing span (and all elements within) are moved using the insertBefore() function. However the button has a registered onclick event handler (using attachEvent()), and once the button is moved, the onclick event will no longer fire.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Sorry, is this IE8 only, or did you only try it on IE8?

Comment: Only tried on IE8. Standards mode

Comment: To answer this, it's necessary to know, how exactly you rearrange the nodes, ie. please show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `insertBefore`, `appendChild` and other DOM manipulation methods keeps event handlers in all browsers, so that's not your problem.

I've tried to reproduce described problem and I see the bug with the click in IE8. The button simply sticks in pressed state and click handler doesn't fire. Never seen such bug before.

To fix this issue you can use `mouseenter` event instead of `mouseover`. (This event is built in in IE, but not in all modern browsers. To make this crossbrowser you can use jQuery `mouseenter`).

JSFiddle links (look in IE8): [with bug](http://jsfiddle.net/t6spj/) and [fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/t6spj/1/)

Comment: Same problem occurs in Opera 12.10. Button moves as normal but becomes unclickable

Comment: `mouseover` event repeats while you move your mouse between child elements of block you're listen events to. So your append child called constantly and when you press the button it's called once again and element gets reappended. So you'll need to add check when element is already in this row like: `if(button.parentNode != cell)`. Crossbrowser fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/t6spj/4/

Comment: That did the trick. It also fixed another issue where css hovers were getting stuck after the menu moved. Thanks.